# Token not allowed in path expression - Reading Configuration file in playframework

Tags: junit, configuration, playframework

I am writing junit test cases in play. I want to read certain configurations from a configuration file. So I am loading that file programatically

```
     private  Configuration additionalConfigurations;
     Config additionalConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf"));
     Config resolConfig = additionalConfig.resolve(ConfigResolveOptions.noSystem());
     additionalConfigurations = new Configuration(scaleBasedConf);

     running(fakeApplication(additionalConfigurations.asMap()), new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
           // test Code
               }
```

While running my test case using "play test" I am getting error "Token not allowed in path expression: '[' (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
" . My configuration where I am getting this error is

```
     Mykey.a.b.c"[]".xyz = "value"
```

I have double quoted square brackets. But still getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of research I finally found out the reason why this is throwing exception. It is because when I do

```
Config additionalConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf"))
additionalConfig.resolve(ConfigResolveOptions.noSystem());
```

Then it parses the configuration file taking double quotes in consideration and thus dont give any exception. However it does 1 more thing, it removes those double quotes while parsing. Then the map which we get after parsing , we are passing it to

```
fakeApplication(additionalConfigurations.asMap()
```

have key like -> Mykey.a.b.c[].xyz

Here, what play does it again parses the map . Now when double quotes are removed, it throws exception . So the solution for it is-

```
     Mykey."\""a.b.c"[]"\"".xyz = "value"
```

Doing this, in first parse it creates string as - > Mykey."a.b.c[]".xyz and so in second parse it goes well and dont throw any exception.

Comment: I was nearly hopeless and you saved my day, thanks! Was there any place in documentation that helped you to solve this issue?